# C# Setting up call to hbase server using thrift - cant find reference to: calculator.client

Tags: c#, thrift

Sorry in advance if this is something simple I just can not find the solution on google.  I am getting started with setting up C# code to connect to an HBASE/Hadoop server.

I have found some examples to start the code/connection.
https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/csharp

I downloaded the nuget package for Thrift and that works.  I am starting at the very beginning and the issue is that for this line below:

```
 Calculator.Client client = new Calculator.Client(protocol);
```

Gets error (type/namespace can not be found.. etc).

Where/how do I add the reference to this class?  I can not find it anywhere and my google searching is not successful

Thank You.

Comment: Calculator has nothing to hadoop. Error message with words "etc" isn't too meaningful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial says it at step 2:

> 2.Generated the [tutorial.thrift](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob_plain;f=tutorial/tutorial.thrift) and [shared.thrift](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob_plain;f=tutorial/shared.thrift) files as discussed [here](https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/).
>
> ```
>  thrift -r --gen csharp tutorial.thrift
> ```

This will leave you with a gen-csharp folder containing the files you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to look at that, but I would think there would be a somewhere I could just download the .dll instead of having to go through all that to just get the .dll for the function I need.  I have the .dlls for the thrift language from .nuget, but for that part I need to go through all that, seems like I could download it from somewhere.

Comment: Thank you, that appears to be what I am missing, I am getting Out Of Memory issues now, but that is not involved with my initial question.  

I would think there would just be a simple place to download these files and not need to go through all this.

Comment: @Brad: For sure it would be cool if we could have a web site that offers a download for every task we have to do, but that will not happen. With regard to Thrift (or SOAP, or REST, etc): If someone offers a precompiled assembly for your use case, then you are lucky. But quite often, that will not be the case, because the whole idea behind having an **language-independent, platform-independent API contract** (the `*.thift` IDL file) is to **enable** as many clients as possible to use a certain API. Prebuilding stuff for 20+ languages in N versions on M platforms is typically not a part of that.